# Generating circular shifts / reduced Latin Squares in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, permutation

Was just wondering what's the most efficient way of generating all the circular shifts of a list in Python. In either direction. For example, given a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, I want to generate either:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 4, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

where the next permutation is generated by moving the last element to the front, or:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 1],
 [3, 4, 1, 2],
 [4, 1, 2, 3]]
```

where the next permutation is generated by moving the first element to the back.

The second case is slightly more interesting to me because it results in a reduced Latin square (the first case also gives a Latin square, just not reduced), which is what I'm trying to use to do experimental block design. It actually isn't that different from the first case since they're just re-orderings of each other, but order does still matter.

The current implementation I have for the first case is:

```
def gen_latin_square(mylist):
    tmplist = mylist[:]
    latin_square = []
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        latin_square.append(tmplist[:])
        tmplist = [tmplist.pop()] + tmplist
    return latin_square
```

For the second case its:

```
def gen_latin_square(mylist):
    tmplist = mylist[:]
    latin_square = []
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        latin_square.append(tmplist[:])
        tmplist = tmplist[1:] + [tmplist[0]]
    return latin_square
```

The first case seems like it should be reasonably efficient to me, since it uses `pop()`, but you can't do that in the second case, so I'd like to hear ideas about how to do this more efficiently. Maybe there's something in `itertools` that will help? Or maybe a double-ended queue for the second case?

Comment: Your implementation don't work -- they are adding list (ints) and lists, which is impossible.  Furthermore, they are appending the same list instance in each iteration, so you will end up with a square that consists of n times the same line.

Comment: Whoops, missed out on that, thanks. Didn't actually test the code :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the first part, the most concise way probably is

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = len(a)
[[a[i - j] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

and for the second part

```
[[a[i - j] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n, 0, -1)]
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]]
```

These should also be much more efficient than your code, though I did not do any timings.

Comment: Wow, didn't think you could do this using list comprehensions! Perhaps I should have thought harder. Props for not having to use any extra modules.

Answer (score 18):

You can use collections.deque:

```
from collections import deque

g = deque([1, 2, 3, 4])

for i in range(len(g)):
    print list(g) #or do anything with permutation
    g.rotate(1) #for right rotation
    #or g.rotate(-1) for left rotation
```

It prints:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
 [4, 1, 2, 3]
 [3, 4, 1, 2]
 [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

To change it for left rotation just replace `g.rotate(1)` with `g.rotate(-1)`.

Comment: That `rotate` method is pretty cool. Never knew that dequeues could do that. Then again, I should probably have read the documentation thoroughly before asking.

Comment: As it is double-ended queue, `rotate` operation is probably efficiently implemented.

Comment: And documentations are indeed our best friends. :)

Answer (score 6):

variation on slicing "conservation law" `a = a[:i] + a[i:]`

```
ns = list(range(5))
ns
Out[34]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

[ns[i:] + ns[:i] for i in range(len(ns))]
Out[36]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
 [2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
 [3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
 [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]]


[ns[-i:] + ns[:-i] for i in range(len(ns))]
Out[38]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library that offers a tool for [cyclic permutations](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.circular_shifts):

```
import more_itertools as mit


mit.circular_shifts(range(1, 5))
# [(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (4, 1, 2, 3)]
```

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift):

> A circular shift is a special kind of cyclic permutation, which in turn is a special kind of permutation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Bruno Lenzi does not seem to work:

```
In [10]: from itertools import cycle

In [11]: x = cycle('ABCD')

In [12]: print [[x.next() for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

I give a correct version below, however the solution by @f5r5e5d is faster.

```
In [45]: def use_cycle(a):
    x=cycle(a)
    for _ in a:
        x.next()
        print [x.next() for _ in a]
   ....:         

In [46]: use_cycle([1,2,3,4])
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]

In [50]: def use_slice(a):
    print [ a[n:] + a[:n] for n in range(len(a)) ]
  ....:     

In [51]: use_slice([1,2,3,4])
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]]

In [54]: timeit.timeit('use_cycle([1,2,3,4])','from __main__ import use_cycle',number=100000)
Out[54]: 0.4884989261627197

In [55]: timeit.timeit('use_slice([1,2,3,4])','from __main__ import use_slice',number=100000)
Out[55]: 0.3103291988372803

In [58]: timeit.timeit('use_cycle([1,2,3,4]*100)','from __main__ import use_cycle',number=100)
Out[58]: 2.4427831172943115

In [59]: timeit.timeit('use_slice([1,2,3,4]*100)','from __main__ import use_slice',number=100)
Out[59]: 0.12029695510864258
```

I removed the print statement in `use_cycle` and `use_slice` for timing purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Using itertools to avoid indexing:

```
x = itertools.cycle(a)
[[x.next() for i in a] for j in a]
```

Answer (score -1):

This will be my solution.

```
#given list
a = [1,2,3,4]
#looping through list
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    #inserting last element at the starting
    a.insert(0,a[len(a)-1])
    #removing the last element
    a = a[:len(a)-1]
    #printing if you want to
    print a
```

This will output the following:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can also use `pop` instead of using list slicing but the problem with `pop` is that it will return something.

Also the above code will work for any length of list. I have not checked for performance of the code. I am assuming that it will work better.

You should have a look at [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for getting a good understanding of List slicing.