# Python : Generating cyclic permutations code (An unexpected code error to be clarified)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, generator, permutation

I didn't manage to correct a code I thought it would work for sure. Any advice to make the code functional is accepted.
Expected outputs of the following code is a list containing a cyclic permuation of the list

`l = [1,2,3,4] (i.e : [[4, 1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 1, 2],[2, 3, 4, 1],[1, 2, 3, 4]])`

Although what I get is : [[2, 3, 4, 1]]

The code :

```
def cycGen(l):
    L=[]
    while not(l in L) :
        L.append(l)
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if l[i] == len(l) :
                l[i]=1
            else :
                l[i] = 1 + l[i] 
    return L
print(cycGen([1,2,3,4]))
```

Another variation of the solution is to consider the following code wich seems unfortunatly not working either :

```
def cycGen(l):
    L=[]
    for k in range(len(l)):
        L.append(l)
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if l[i] == len(l) :
                l[i]=1
            else :
                l[i] = 1 + l[i]   
    return L
```

Help me with your generous knowlege sharing please.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313900/generating-cyclic-permutations-reduced-latin-squares-in-python/48376124#48376124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code sample, the line `L.append(l)` appends a "reference" (loosely speaking) to the list `l` to the end of `L`, rather than appending a copy as you seem to be expecting.  Thus, when `l` is later modified, the reference to it contained in `L` is modified as well, and so when `l in L` is tested, `l` will equal the reference to itself in `L`, and so the loop will end.  The same basic problem causes your second code sample to return multiples of the same list rather than several different lists.

To store a copy of `l` at the current point in time in `L` instead, use `L.append(l[:])`.

Comment: Can i get a detailed material from your choice to avoid such confusions in future ?

Comment: Is this syntaxe problem existed for all the python versions or is it just concerning the python 3.0 version ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

d = deque(a)
for _ in range(len(a)):
    d.rotate()
    print(list(d))
```

Which gives you the output:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As mentioned in [Efficient way to shift a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150108/efficient-way-to-shift-a-list-in-python)

Comment: You can just use `for _ in a:`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is just:

```
In [12]: x = [1,2,3,4]

In [13]: [x[i:]+x[:i] for i in range(len(x))]
Out[13]: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way:

```
>>> def cycGen(l):
        size = len(l)
        return [[l[(i+j)%size] for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]

>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> print cycGen(l)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a generator too:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def next_pos(max):
    i = 0
    while True:
        for n in xrange(max):
            yield n + i
        i += 1

pos = next_pos(len(a))

b = []
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    n = []
    for j in xrange(len(a)):
        m = pos.next()
        if m >= len(a):
            m -= len(a)
        n.append(a[m])
    b.append(n)

print b
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]]
```